# What is the purpose of arr[i] - '0' in the following code snippet?

Tags: java, arrays, string

This is the code given to us by our teacher, when I asked why we subtract '0' from arr[i] she simply said it is used to exclude anything which is not number. Can anyone explain how it works?

```
//program to print the sum of all the digits in a string
//
import java.io.IOException;
class CSumOfDigit
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String str="67281";
        char arr[]=str.toCharArray();
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
           sum=sum+(arr[i]-'0');
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of digits is:"+sum);
     }
}
```

Comment: A verbose way to get the same result as `int sum = str.chars().sum() - '0' * str.length();`

Answer (score 1):

It does not "exclude anything which is not number."

It converts the numeric value of digit characters ('0', '1', ..., '9') to the corresponding `int` values (0, 1, ..., 9).

The numeric value of the `char` '0' is 48, so if you subtract '0' from '0' you get 48 - 48 == 0.

The numeric value of the `char` '1' is 49, so if you subtract '0' from '1' you get 49 - 48 == 1.

and so on...

This results in computing the sum of the digits of the number represented by the input `String`. It will only produce a meaningful result if the input `String` contains only digits.

Answer (score 1):

You have `String str="67281";` that is a `String` you cannot do normal math operations on `String`.

Than you convert that `String` to a and array of `char`. You can do math operations with `char` but the result would not be the one you expect. In Java characters are represented by numbers (lookup ASCII table).

'0' is 48, '1' is 49, etc..

By substracting the '0' (48) from the `char` you are getting the real numerical value of that number.

Comment: Thank you, have a good day :)